# Acumatica Import Scenario items getting partially processed

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to import All customers to the system but it keeps giving me this error

[image]

What does View name: Group mean?

I created a the Customer Access for All customers
                Data Provider with Data object 
            and Import scenario

Is there any other way to import All the customers into the system so that I can implement Row-level security?

This is the import Scenario page
[image: import scenario]

Comment: Please the import scenario creation page with details from this screen it's impossible to say what is the reason

Comment: I have included the import scenario page in the question, please go through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first set **Group's** ID and only then the **Customers'** IDs.
Here is working example:
[image]

Here is the Data Provider:
[image]

And finally the Import Scenario:
[image]

Also before importing records check that all the Customers in the importing data are already created in the system, otherwise you will get errors on Customers.

Comment: Thank you for a brief reply. I followed your steps but still getting the same error,

Comment: @user8534573 are you sure that you already have the customer in the system? This scenario is working perfect for me.

Comment: yes I do have the customer in the system, I think I should redo the process